# Sent a message to group from ejabberd server

Tags: ejabberd

Sent a message to group from ejabberd server but i get

> Hook user_receive_packet crashed when running
> mod_mam:user_receive_packet

```
send_message(Type, From, To, Subject, Body, StaticNumber) ->
    CodecOpts = ejabberd_config:codec_options(),
    try xmpp:decode(
          #xmlel{name = <<"message">>,
                 attrs = [{<<"to">>, To },
                          {<<"from">>,From},
                          {<<"type">>, Type},
                          {<<"id">>, p1_rand:get_string()}],
                 children =
                     [#xmlel{name = <<"subject">>,
                             children = [{xmlcdata, Subject}]},
                      #xmlel{name = <<"groupcontent">>,
                             attrs = [{<<"sendername">>, <<"Admin">>},
                             {<<"acknowStatus">>, <<"0">>},{<<"fromadmin">>, StaticNumber}],
                             children = []},     
                      #xmlel{name = <<"body">>,
                             children = [{xmlcdata, Body}]}]},
          ?NS_CLIENT, CodecOpts) of
        #message{from = JID} = Msg ->
            State = #{jid => JID},
             ejabberd_hooks:run_fold(user_send_packet, JID#jid.lserver, {Msg, State}, []),
             ejabberd_router:route(Msg)
    catch _:{xmpp_codec, Why} ->
            {error, xmpp:format_error(Why)}
    end.
```

function call :

> send_message("normal",
> list_to_binary("123456789@xmpp.designcafe.com"),
> list_to_binary("6ff3d0a4-c281-41bd-a262-c65bd767014d@mix.xmpp.designcafe.com"),
> list_to_binary("text"), <<"test">>, <<"123456789">>);

I could not fix above issue

Answer (score 0):

> send_message("normal",

Instead of "normal", you must provide groupchat as a binary, that is:

> send_message(<<"groupchat">>,

What that change it works for me using ejabberd 22.05. It's important that From is an existing account, and it joined the MIX Channel. Of course the MIX Channel must exist too.